# How can python __new__ method return a string or unicode object instead of class object

Tags: python, object

How can I create a new `string` object with Python `__new__` method so that the string object should have class attributes also.

For example, I have tested this in Maya:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(str, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(A, str).__new__(str)

    def __init__(self, obj):         
        self.obj =str(obj)

    def hai(self):
        print 'hai new obj. you are not string object. you are only cls object'

objA =A('object01')

objA.hai()
```

> **Result**: 'hai new obj. you are not string object. you are only cls object'

```
objA
```

> **Result**: <**main**.A object at 0x22799710>

I have tested the same with PyNode class of (PyMel)

```
objB =PyNode('object01')
objB
```

> **Result**: nt.Transform(u'object01')

But PyNode object is giving a unicode or string object. That means `objB` can be used directly as string or unicode but `objA` can't be used like that

How can I get something like `objB` ouput?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
class A(str)
```

to make `A` a subclass of `str`:

```
class A(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def hai(self):
        print('hai new obj. you are not string object. you are only cls object')

objA =A('object01')

objA.hai()
assert isinstance(objA, str)
```

Comment: Hi one more question: Suppose objA.rename('object02') is there. After renaming this to 'object02', objA should be updated and it should return 'object02' name. I need not recreate new object objA =A('object02'). Any Idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this won't be possible as str is immutable in nature, you have to recreate/reinitialize a new str object.

Comment: @SubbuAddanki: Yes, that is impossible because `str`s are immutable.